# How to keep an icon in the correct position? (right of field and field re-positions)

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

In general, I am trying to have an icon which stays to the right of a field. I need it to work in Firefox, Chrome, IE11 and IE8

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8f6N/3/

There is a fieldset which can be expanded or collapsed. When the fieldset changes, the fields below it move up or down to compensate for the movement. When this happens, Firefox is unique in that the **icons do not move with the field's body**.

I find that if I use **relative positioning** rather than **absolute**, the icon will move with the field like it should. However, then there is some **white space being put below each field**, which I do not want.

Advice is appreciated in the following questions:

1. A way for firefox to move the icon with the rest of the field?
2. A way to use relative positioning and not have the extra space being
   inserted below the field?
3. Alternatively, a better way to skin this cat?

Code used in fiddle:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var fieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
        title: 'Simple Collapsible Fieldset',
        collapsible: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'label',
            text: 'Watch the icon and collapse this fieldset'
        }]
    });

    var textBoxWithInfoIcon = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        fieldLabel: 'Example',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (me) {
                var icon = me.getEl().down('.x-form-item-body').createChild({
                    cls: 'x-form-info-icon',
                    tag: 'img',
                    src: 'broken',
                    width: 16,
                    height: 18,
                        'data-qtip': 'an example textfield to simulate this icon which does not move',
                        'data-qtitle': 'Field Information'
                });
                var xPosition = 130;
                var yPosition = 0;
                icon.alignTo(me.getEl(), 'tl-tr', [xPosition, yPosition]);
            }
        }
    });

    var textBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        fieldLabel: 'Example'
    });

    var textBoxWithInfoIcon2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        fieldLabel: 'Example',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (me) {
                var icon = me.getEl().down('.x-form-item-body').createChild({
                    cls: 'x-form-info-icon',
                    tag: 'img',
                    src: 'broken',
                    width: 16,
                    height: 18,
                        'data-qtip': 'an example textfield to simulate this icon which does not move',
                        'data-qtitle': 'Field Information'
                });
                var xPosition = 130;
                var yPosition = 0;
                icon.alignTo(me.getEl(), 'tl-tr', [xPosition, yPosition]);
            }
        }
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Title',
        frame: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        items: [fieldSet, textBoxWithInfoIcon, textBox, textBoxWithInfoIcon2],
        renderTo: document.body
    });
});
```

**p.s.** There are a lot of questions with similar titles, yet as far as I've found they don't have to deal with a collapsing fieldset and just use absolute positioning in their css.

**EDIT**

More details after working with it for a while: After trying to add an info icon to a field's body, the input of the field is at the same level as the icon, but the input is set to take up 100% of the width. I am not sure where/how I can change this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning of the injected icons is not the best solution for the info icons after fields.

Much better would be to add a  after the input field parent . That would solve everything: Input would get shorter to make space for the icon, no need to calculate and set position of the icon, no problems with collapsible fieldset as of now.

I think you need this plugin: [Form Field Icon Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/form-field-icon-plugin/)